# Send newsletter

Tags: magento2, email, email-templates, newsletter

I have freshly installed Magento 2,

And I could not find a way to send the newsletter email,

There are options to queue template, but it is never sent,

and the start date is always different from the one which I set.

What should I do?

**NOTE** 
I set email configuration with my credentials.

Answer (score 1):

Newsletters are sent by a cron job in batches. Have you got your cron jobs set up correctly?

For details of how to setup cron jobs see https://www.mageplaza.com/kb/how-to-configure-cronjob-schedule-tasks-magento-2.html

Comment: Do I still need their extensions?

Comment: No the guide is for default Magento installation. Newsletters can be sent without any need for extensions.

Comment: I set up, but no success.

Comment: I would suspect the cron job isn't running. Have you checked your logs to see if it is? In var/system.log I have it stamped: Cron Job newsletter_send_all is run [] []

Comment: In the log **cron.log** about newsletter I found this : ** [2019-02-18 10:49:36] main.INFO: Cron Job newsletter_send_all is missed at 2019-02-18 09:25:00 [] [] 
** , sorry for late response.

Comment: It was because of the newsletter date, now I have some different error, but that's ok I will try it now.

Comment: @CrhisC, now when I resolve the error, I don't see log for sending newsletters.

Answer (score 0):

You can run command

> php bin/magento cron:run

to run Cron manually or set Cronjob to make it run automatically

**Note**: I had to install SMTP extension (https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-smtp/) to send emails from my localhost.

Comment: I success at sending email for forgot the password, but I couldn't do it for the newsletter, cause probably corn isn't run, I think that running command won't have effort because of start date (time) isn't correct, Magento always overrides it with random time.

Comment: Have you set timezone to yours one in Configuration settings? Different timezone cause this issue

Comment: Yes, that was the problem, now I set but still no sending, I will use that mageplaza SMTP extension and try.